# Cloning a gameObject which use properties similar to original gameobject

Tags: unity, c#

How to make clone of gameobject have the same properties as the original gameobject just placed right to it and the clone should fire exactly parallel to original character.
Every property should be same.

actually I have a player having 4 skills and I wanted to add one more skill to my player (5th skill) so that it can clone itself and do everything like its original player and one restriction will be there is clone player should be just right(2-3 units) to the original player.

Comment: This question can be answered on your own by reading the API.

Answer (score 0):

[Instantiate()](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)

```
var clone = Instantiate(originalGameObject, position, orientation)(GameObject);
```

See [this tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/instantiate) for more information.

I'd encourage you to read the scripting documentation or try some tutorials - this type of answer is very easy to find on your own.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply..I have taken these information from  tutorials. let me explain first every thing related to my problem ...actually I have a player having 4 skills and I wanted to add one more skill to my player (5th skill) so that it can clone itself and do everything like its original player and one restriction will be there is clone player should be just right(2-3 units) to the original player.

Comment: @Rajeev Chauhan Details about your question belong in your question, not in comments. You should edit your question to describe exactly what behaviour you want, what you've tried so far, and what isn't working.

Comment: ok thanks for your suggestion ..issue is now resolved any way